# How can I open a interactive PDF (created with Mingmanager software) in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, pdf, document-management

I'm following a on-line course about intellectual property. The professor uses interactive maps or schemes where the themes are displayed. Beside every theme is a plus sign wich opens new content when clicked. The presentation was created with MindManager (Mindjet) but the files are downloadable in PDF, so they can be viewed with Acrobat Reader.

[image]

The thing is I've tried with the Ubuntu document viewer and with Okular but all I get is one page that says "click to start Mindjet presentation" and it doesn't work.

Here are the conceptual maps if you need to read the instructions or [download them](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/people/tfisher/IP/IP%20Maps.htm)

Comment: Try [Adobe Acrobat](http://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/) for Linux.

Comment: I tried it and an error ocurred, it says "A 3D data parsing error ocurred"

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and tried one of the files and it works, but it is a bit tricky.
First you need adobe reader 9.4.1 (not a newer one because I read that adobe does not launch newer versions for linux with flash capabilities). The link is this one: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/enu/

There are still some differences. The plus sign is not working, but if you highlight any of the boxes and click right on the mouse, a menu appears where you can select to collapse topic, show 1 level, 2 levels and all levels. For highlighting correctly (in blue) the boxes I actually must click above the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/ and was able to view interactive PDFs properly.